# How to center an element in the middle of its parent?

Tags: html, css

[image: 1]

Hi, is there any way I can achieve this layout without using `position: absolute`, preferably using flexbox? I want the middle element to be horizontally centered in the parent element, regardless of other elements.
Currently I'm using this on the middle element. (because in my case middle of the div is the middle of the window):

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

But in this solution the parent does not respect the middle element's height, so it is not an ideal solution for me.

Note: I've already tried using this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

This however does not produce the intended result (first two middle blocks should be split in the middle by the line):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#block {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}

#middle-line {
  border: none;
  border-left: dashed;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <hr id="middle-line">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="block" style="width: 120px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 120px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="block" style="width: 120px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div id="block" style="width: 120px"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` and `align-items: center` in case you need to align it vertically

Comment: Look into how flexboxes work, this guide will give you everything you need to know about every setting and how to use it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I think position: absolute approach is ok. You can give position: relative to the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

This code is to go into the attributes of the code like this:

```
.part {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Order of that code does not matter. (May have made a syntax error because I usually use Sass.)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on twitter by accident

https://twitter.com/EricVicenti/status/1645496262161203202

```css
.example1 .block-1 {
  width: 40px;
}

.example1 .block-2 {
  width: 125px;
}

.example2 .block-1 {
  width: 175px;
}

.example2 .block-2 {
  width: 25px;
}

.example3 .block-1 {
  width: 40px;
}

.example3 .block-2 {
  width: 100px;
}


html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: system-ui;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.root {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.left-container, .right-container {
  flex-basis: 0%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.text {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.block {
  background-color: #5744ff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Credit: https://twitter.com/vincentriemer/status/1645525394542723072 -->

<div class="root example1">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="block block-1"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text">Title</h1>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="block block-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="root example2">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="block block-1"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text">Pushed Title</h1>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="block block-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="root example3">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="block block-1"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text">Title may be very long</h1>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="block block-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```